# Upgrade to Jammy "failed", stuck partially upgraded

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Yesterday I tried to upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04, and late in the process I got a message saying that some package (I think it was Python 3 point something) hadn't installed properly. Later it showed that message again, this time saying that because it couldn't finish the upgrade it would try to fix some things but maybe it wouldn't be bootable afterwards. No instructions on what I should do shown. I did try opening a terminal and typing "python3" and that did look right: python 3 didn't seem to be missing.

Eventually I did end up turning off the laptop. Kernel panic. I managed to fix it by booting an earlier kernel version instead. It seems to have upgraded, but a lot of icons are missing, either showing as gears or as file-not-found icons.

The software updater thinks I should get rid of some "old kernel updates that are no longer needed" but now that I can only boot an old kernel I don't want to do that. It seems able to find new updates but unable to install them for some reason, I can get it to attempt, but then it fails, showing this (screenshot: "Softwareopdatering / Pakkehandling mislykkedes / Installation eller fjernelse af en softwarepakke mislykkedes.", which means something along the lines of "Software update / Package action failed / Installation or removal of a software package failed.") [image: error message, see text above]

I can figure out how to use the laptop despite all the icons looking the same (would be nice if it were fixable though) but being able to update anything (or install or remove anything) is a bit too limiting. So how do I get it working again?

Edit:
I tried running "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade", got this (if there's some command line flag to get the output in English, I'd rather use that than translate things myself, or I guess I could try putting the laptop in English if that's really the only way):

```
Henter:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                            
Havde:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                
Henter:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Henter:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11,4 kB]
Henter:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [608 B]
Henter:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99,8 kB]
Henter:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [90,8 kB]
Henter:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [95,1 kB]
Henter:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Henter:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12,5 kB]
Hentede 536 kB på 3s (201 kB/s)                                             
Indlæser pakkelisterne... Færdig
Opbygger afhængighedstræ... Færdig
Læser tilstandsoplysninger... Færdig
7 pakker kan opgraderes. Kør »apt list --upgradable« for at se dem.
Indlæser pakkelisterne... Færdig
Opbygger afhængighedstræ... Færdig
Læser tilstandsoplysninger... Færdig
Beregner opgraderingen... Færdig
Følgende pakker blev installeret automatisk, og behøves ikke længere:
  app-install-data-partner cdparanoia cdrskin dvd+rw-tools dvgrab gcc-11-base:i386 giblib1
  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gnome-screenshot k3b k3b-data k3b-i18n libabsl20200923 libaom0
  libcamel-1.2-62 libcbor0.6 libclang1-11 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcodec2-0.9 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libdap27
  libdapclient6v5 libdav1d4 libdrm-intel1:i386 libegl1-mesa libepsilon1 libextutils-pkgconfig-perl
  libfluidsynth2 libfwupdplugin1 libgavl1 libgdal28 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgeos-3.9.0 libgl1-mesa-glx
  libglu1-mesa:i386 libgsoap-2.8.104 libgupnp-1.2-0 libicu67:i386 libidn11 libieee1284-3:i386
  libigdgmm11 libjsoncpp24 libk3b7 libk3b7-extracodecs libkdecorations2private8 libkf5cddb5
  libkf5pulseaudioqt2 libllvm11 libllvm12 libllvm12:i386 libmbedcrypto3 libmbedtls12 libmbedx509-0
  libmgba libmimetic0v5 libmlt++3 libmlt6 libmms0 libmozjs-78-0 libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libneon27-gnutls
  libnetcdf18 libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libntfs-3g883 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libodbccr2
  libodbccr2:i386 libofa0 libopencv-calib3d4.5 libopencv-contrib4.5 libopencv-core4.5 libopencv-dnn4.5
  libopencv-features2d4.5 libopencv-flann4.5 libopencv-highgui4.5 libopencv-imgcodecs4.5
  libopencv-imgproc4.5 libopencv-ml4.5 libopencv-objdetect4.5 libopencv-video4.5 libopengl0:i386
  libopenjp2-7:i386 liborcus-0.16-0 liborcus-parser-0.16-0 libotf0 libpci3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386
  libperl5.34:i386 libplacebo72 libpoppler-glib8:i386 libpoppler111 libpoppler111:i386
  libpoppler118:i386 libproj19 libpython3.9 libpython3.9-dev libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib
  libqgpgme7 libqhull8.0 libqt5keychain1 libquicktime2 libsane1:i386 libsnmp40:i386 libssl1.1:i386
  libstdc++-9-dev libtinyxml2-8 liburing1 libvpx6 libvpx6:i386 libwebp6 libwebp6:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libx264-160 libx265-192 libxcb-xtest0 libxmlb1 linux-headers-5.13.0-51
  linux-headers-5.13.0-51-generic linux-image-5.13.0-51-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-51-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-51-generic ltrace obsession odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 ofono
  python-pygame-sdl2 python3-nose python3-simplejson python3.9 python3.9-dev python3.9-minimal
  recordmydesktop ruby2.7 trojita trojita-data trojita-l10n ttf-ubuntu-font-family ttf-unifont
  wesnoth-1.16-data wesnoth-1.16-music x11proto-input-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev
  xul-ext-ubufox
Brug »sudo apt autoremove« til at fjerne dem.
Følgende pakker er blevet holdt tilbage:
  colobot libboost-regex1.74.0 libsource-highlight4v5 wesnoth
Følgende pakker vil blive opgraderet:
  linux-firmware wireless-regdb xdg-desktop-portal
3 opgraderes, 0 nyinstalleres, 0 afinstalleres og 4 opgraderes ikke.
1529 ikke fuldstændigt installerede eller afinstallerede.
1 standard security update
264 kB/238 MB skal hentes fra arkiverne.
Efter denne handling, vil 4.096 B yderligere diskplads være brugt.
Vil du fortsætte? [J/n] j
Henter:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 xdg-desktop-portal amd64 1.14.4-1ubuntu2~22.04.1 [264 kB]
Hentede 264 kB på 3s (103 kB/s)              
Sætter python3 (3.10.4-0ubuntu2) op ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
  File "/usr/share/games/renpy/launcher/game/gui7/code.py", line 283
    l = re.sub(ur'_\((\".*?\")\)', replace, l)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
error running python rtupdate hook renpy
dpkg: fejl under behandling af pakken python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: afhængighedsproblemer forhindrer konfiguration af lsb-release:
 lsb-release afhænger af python3:any; men:
  Pakken python3 er ikke sat op endnu.

dpkg: fejl under behandling af pakken lsb-release (--configure):
 afhængighedsproblemer - efterlader den ukonfigureret
Ingen apportrapport skrevet da fejlbeskeden indikerer, at det er en opfølgningsfejl fra en tidligere fejl.
 Der opstod fejl under behandlingen:
 python3
 lsb-release
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit: Somehow since space hasn't been a problem I've sometimes left stuff installed after not using it for months or even years, so maybe I should have uninstalled some things before upgrading, but I guess now is a bit late to realize that would maybe have helped, at least by making the upgrade take less time as there would have been less stuff to download new versions of.

Other edit: looking t the error messages I got in Danish, I think it's having trouble updating the python3 package because another package, probably renpy, was depending on the old version. But it's kinda late in the evening, so it might take me some time to check if that's what was happening.

Comment: can you try running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` in the terminal, and post output here?

Comment: Backup your data. Be prepared to reinstall 22.04 from a LiveUSB. Perhaps you won't need to use those precautions, but you will certainly be sorry if you do need them and are unprepared for it.

Answer (score 1):

After trying `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and posting the output, I figured out from this part:

```
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
  File "/usr/share/games/renpy/launcher/game/gui7/code.py", line 283
    l = re.sub(ur'_\((\".*?\")\)', replace, l)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
error running python rtupdate hook renpy
```

that it seemed the version of Renpy that was already present was somehow incompatible with the version of Python 3 that was being installed, so I tried uninstalling Renpy with `sudo apt remove renpy`. That also seemed to update some other packages, and after that, I was able to get `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to work, and after restarting the laptop, I didn't need to select an old kernel, and the icons also look normal now. Installing and uninstalling and updating packages also seems to work now.

Comment: Nice job! Glad you fixed it.